# Devise Invitable using multiple fields for emails in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, devise

Hi I'm currently using `devise_invitable` gem to allow a user to invite multiple users.

However, my current form looks like this:

```
.user-unit
  %h2 Invite
  = form_tag batch_invite_users_path, :method => :post do
    = label_tag "Emails"
    = text_field_tag :user_emails, @invalid_emails.try(:join, ','), class: 'input-xxlarge'
    %br
    = submit_tag "Send", class: 'btn-primary'

- content_for :javascript do
  :javascript
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#user_emails').tokenField();
    })
```

It allows multiple emails, but I want to have a form that has 4 fields for emails and then every email will be invited.

Just like this: http://oi39.tinypic.com/2qn5kdk.jpg

My controller looks like this:

```
  def batch_invite
    if request.post? && params[:user_emails]
      valid_emails = []
      @invalid_emails = []
      params[:user_emails].split(",").each do |email|
        if email =~ Devise.email_regexp
          user = User.invite!({:email => email}, current_user)
          user.roles << Role.find(3)
          valid_emails << email
        else
          @invalid_emails << email
        end
      end
      if valid_emails.empty?
        flash[:notice] = "No email have been sent."
      else
        redirect_to :back
        flash[:notice] = "An invitation has been sent to #{valid_emails.join(',')}."
      end
    end
  end
```

From the `params[:user_emails]` I just splitted it to become array.

How can I achieve 4 email fields? Should I add 4 different email columns just to achieve it?

Like I'll create `email_field_1` , `email_field_2` , `email_field_3` , `email_field_4` and so on?

Any workarounds will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `attr_accesor`:

```
attr_accessor :email_field1, :email_field2, :email_field3, :email_field4
```

then in form you can use:

```
= f.text_field :email_field1
= f.text_field :email_field2
= f.text_field :email_field3
= f.text_field :email_field4
```

these fields will be sent as params on submit and you can play with them in controller.

adding these fields to `attr_accesor` will require to add them to `attr_accessible`